# Open ID Token vs Oauth Token

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

I am new to OAuth and OpenId, and after reading multiple pages and information I still do not feel confident at all.

My goal would be to create an iOS Application that communicates with my BE. I need the iOS app to authenticate the user to access their resources.

Reading about OAuth, the solution seems to be straight forward. Just use the `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE` to make the App have an `Access Token`. This way I am authorizing my iOS app to access user's data. When the iOS app calls `https://example.org/user` with the access token, the resource service (my BE server) can get the access token and call the introspection API to know to which user the access token is bound to, and return the correct user data. Since authorization needs authentication to be made in the first place, having the access token would mean that the user is (or at least was) authenticated.

First thing that confuses me: According to the OAuth specs, OAuth is not an authentication protocol, but still the protocol authenticates the user using the user's credentials. **Why is OAuth asking the user for credentials, instead of relying on another protocol/flow for user authentication?** Such protocol would just acknowledge to OAuth that the authentication was successful.

This first issue made me start reading about Open ID Connect specification and the ID Token. This token would be received by the iOS app. **What is the iOS App supposed to do with it?** I can already get the user information calling the `/user` endpoint. **How would this ID Token be an advantage?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr**

- Access token (OAuth 2.0) - authorize against OAuth protected
  endpoints.
- ID Token (OIDC) - authentiation by client application.
- Authorization server authentication - It's there to detect
  authenticity of end user involved in both protocols (pseudo
  authentication from client application perspective)

---

**OAuth is not an authentication protocol, but still the protocol contain a step to authenticate the user using the user's credentials**

Correct, OAuth is not an authentication protocol. It is for authorization, which means identifying there are correct access grants to access a protected resource (protected resource ? ex:- An API, A photo stored in a backend).

So why you see end user login dialog ? Well that is the job of **authorization server**. It authenticate end user to be known by it and then issue the access token to client (client == in simple terms the application which end user uses). So yes there is an authenitcation happening, but this is not applicable to your client application or protected endpoint. One can define this as an pseudo authentication.

**OpenID Connect - For authentication of client application**

In the original RFC ([RFC-6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)), OAuth 2.0 was defined as a framework. OpenID Connect was an extension that built on this framework. What it provide ? Well as you found out, it introduce the ID Token. And ID token is issued by authorization server to be consumed by your client application. It contains end user identity information in JWT format. By validating integrity of this token, your client application can **authenticate the end user**. And access token ? That's there to used against protected endpoint. It doesn't say anything about end user to client.